# Finding a value within a dictionary of ranges - python

Tags: python, dictionary, range

I'm comparing 2 files with an initial identifier column, start value, and end value. The second file contains corresponding identifiers and another value column.

Ex.

File 1:

```
A     200     900
A     1000    1200
B     100     700
B     900     1000
```

File 2:

```
A     103
A     200
A     250
B     50
B     100
B     150
```

I would like to find all values from the second file that are contained within the ranges found in the first file so that my output would look like:

```
A     200
A     250
B     100
B     150
```

For now I have created a dictionary from the first file with a list of ranges:
Ex.

```
if Identifier in Dictionary:
    Dictionary[Identifier].extend(range(Start, (End+1)))
else:
    Dictionary[Identifier] = range(Start, (End+1))
```

I then go through the second file and search for the value within the dictionary of ranges:
Ex.

```
if Identifier in Dictionary:
    if Value in Dictionary[Identifier]:
    OutFile.write(Line + "\n")
```

While not optimal this works for relatively small files, however I have several large files and this program is proving terribly inefficient. I need to optimize my program so that it will run much faster.

Comment: Do the identifiers appear in the same order in both files? Are the values and ranges always in sorted order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
ident_ranges = defaultdict(list)
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1
    for row in f1:
        ident, start, end = row.split()
        start, end = int(start), int(end)
        ident_ranges[ident].append((start, end))
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2, open('out.txt', 'w') as output:  
    for line in f2:
        ident, value = line.split()
        value = int(value)
        if any(start <= value <= end for start, end in ident_ranges[ident]):
            output.write(line)
```

**Notes**:  Using a `defaultdict` allows you to add ranges to your dictionary without first checking for the existence of a key.  Using `any` allows for short circuiting of the range check.  Using chained comparision is a nice Python syntactic shortcut (`start <= value <= end`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got large ranges and your problem is essentially just a bunch of comparisons, it's almost certainly faster to store a start/end tuple than the whole range (especially since what you have now is going to duplicate most of the numbers in the ranges if two happen to overlap).

```
# Building the dict
if not ident in d:
    d[ident] = (lo, hi)
else:
    old_lo, old_hi = d[ident]
    d[ident] = (min(lo, old_lo), max(hi, old_hi))
```

Then your comparisons just look like:

```
# comparing...
if ident in d:
    if d[ident][0] <= val <= d[ident][1]:
        outfile.write(line+'\n')
```

Both parts of this will go faster if you aren't making separate checks for `if ident in d`. Python dictionaries are nice and fast, so just make the call to it in the first place. You've got the ability to provide defaults to the dictionary, so use it. I haven't benchmarked this or anything to see what the speedup is, but you'd certainly get some, and it certainly works:

```
# These both make use of the following somewhat silly hack:
# In Python, None is treated as less than everything (even -float('inf))
# and empty containers (e.g. (), [], {}) are treated as greater than everything.
# So we use the tuple ((), None) as if it was (float('inf'), float('-inf))

for line in file1:
    ident, lo, hi = line.split()
    lo = int(lo)
    hi = int(hi)
    old_lo, old_hi = d.get(ident, ((), None))
    d[ident] = (min(lo, old_lo), max(hi, old_hi))

# comparing:
for line in file2:
    ident, val = line.split()
    val = int(val)
    lo, hi = d.get(ident, ((), None))
    if lo <= val <= hi:
        outfile.write(line) # unless you stripped it off, this still has a \n
```

The above code is what I was using to test; it runs on a `file2` of a million lines in a couple seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to construct `range(START, END)`? That seems quite wasteful when you can do:

```
if START <= x <= END:
    # process
```

Checking if the value is in the range is slow because a) you've had to construct the list and b) perform a linear search over the list to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
In [27]: ranges=defaultdict(list)

In [28]: with open("file1") as f:
    for line in f:
        name,st,end=line.split()
        st,end=int(st),int(end)
        ranges[name].append([st,end])
   ....:         

In [30]: ranges
Out[30]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [[200, 900], [1000, 1200]], 'B': [[100, 700], [900, 1000]]})

In [29]: with open("file2") as f:
    for line in f:
        name,val=line.split()
        val=int(val)
        if any(y[0]<=val<=y[1] for y in ranges[name]):
            print name,val
   ....:             
A 200
A 250
B 100
B 150
```

Answer (score 0):

Neat trick: Python lets you do `in` comparisons with `xrange` objects, which is much faster than doing `in` with a `range`, and much more memory efficient.

So, you can do

```
from collections import defaultdict

rangedict = defaultdict(list)
...
rangedict[ident].append(xrange(start, end+1))
...

for i in rangedict:
    for r in rangedict[i]:
        if v in r:
            print >>outfile, line
```