# Checking for a dictionary key which is a range of integers

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, range, try-catch

I'm building a dictionary of manufacturers. It would look something like this:

```
mfgs =     {17491: 'DS', 6543: 'AC'}
```

In this scenario, I need to represent a range of integers that all refer to the same manufacturer. (e.g. 1 - 99 are all manufactured by DC)

I've seen that you can create a dictionary key in which a range is represented.

```
mfgs =     {17491: 'DS', 6543: 'AC', (1,99): 'DC'}
```

Later on, I will have an integer grabbed from an external file. Depending upon the value encountered, I will log the appropriate manufacturer into another file.

I am unclear on how to check for the presence of a valid key/value pair (whether a number or a range of numbers) and log "Unknown" if neither is found without building an expanding if/then that accounts for keys defined in the dictionary.

It seems like try/except is appropriate, but if 21 is encountered, mfg[21] fails and it shouldn't.

Comment: Actually this may be a better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392623/finding-a-value-within-a-dictionary-of-ranges-python

Comment: Thanks. I had found the first one but couldn't understand the answers. (New to Python and programming.). I'll read these questions more carefully.

Comment: Cool! If you have a specific question as to why that one didn't answer your question then feel free to ask another question

Comment: I think merely need to type out the example and run it to see how it works. Maybe understanding will strike. :)

Comment: Hmm, on closer inspection neither of them do exactly what you're trying to do here. I've reopened the question and answered it - hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than just a simple hashmap (i.e. dictionary) lookup. Hashmaps lookup particular keys, not whether a key is in range of any of the existing keys.

You have two simple options.

1. If you know the ranges ahead of time, convert the integer into a range before looking it up:

   ```
   def range_from_id(manufacturer_id):
       if 1 <= manufacturer_id <= 99:
           return (1, 99)
       return manufacturer_id

   manufacturer_id = ... from file ...
   manufacturer_range = range_from_id(manufacturer_id)
   manufacturer = mfgs.get(manufacturer_range, "Unknown")
   ```
2. If you don't, then keep track of the ranges in a separate dictionary, and loop through all possible values:

   ```
   mfgs = {17491: 'DS', ...}
   mfg_ranges = {(1, 99): 'DC', ...}

   def lookup_manufacturer(manufacturer_id):
       # direct look-up:
       if manufacturer_id in mfgs: 
           return mfgs[manufacturer_id]

       # range look-up:
       for (start, end), mfg in mfg_ranges.items():
           if start <= manufacturer_id <= end:
               return mfg

       return "Unknown"
   ```

   If speed is important, note that this option will take `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of ranges you have. A more proper way to do it would be using binary trees, as [amit answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852283/key-lookup-from-a-data-structure-based-on-range). This would require using a 3rd party library like [bintrees](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.2).

Comment: So with option two, you're suggesting _two_ dictionaries? One with ids known ahead of time and one with the range. Is that correct?

Comment: @tcv: Yeah. It makes it simpler because they are indeed two different lookup strategies. Note that with this approach, you aren't really taking advantage of the dictionary aspect of the ranges dictionary. It may as well be a list of `(start_range, end_range, id)` - you're iterating through the dictionary and checking all the ranges manually. There must exist a data structure which does this more efficiently but I don't know what it is off the top of my head.

Comment: I found another way to do it the makes sense to my n00b programming brain. What is the best way to deal with this? Post my solution? Or accept yours? Both would obviously work.

Comment: @tcv: Cool! If it's different from mine then post it & accept your own answer, that is perfectly acceptable

Comment: Thanks. I've added it. It seems to work well for me. Any other manufacturers will be added to the dictionary therein. Due to my n00b-status perhaps you can tell me if I'm heading for disaster.

Comment: Is it appropriate to try this then ask questions about your answer? Is it appropriate to point to the code elsewhere like a Github repo?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. Please note that i is there because we're in a for-loop iterating through found items. mfgs is a dictionary pre-populated.

```
try:
    drivers_list[i]['mfg'] = mfgs[mfg] # Attempt to store in dictionary
except:
    if 1 <= mfg <= 31:   # On exception, see if it's the known mfg.
        drivers_list[i]['mfg'] = 'The known manufacturer'  # Between 1 and 31
    else:
        drivers_list[i]['mfg'] = 'Unknown' # otherwise post unknown
```

Comment: Regarding telling you if you're heading for disaster: this works if you only have one range, of `(1, 31)`. But how would you do it if you have two ranges, say `(1, 31)` and `(39, 55)`? What about 3 ranges? What about `n` ranges? Is there a better way to do it than a lot of `if`/`elif`/`elif`s?

Comment: The elif would be the only way I could think of off the top of my head. In this case, I am actually dealing with only one range. I'm cataloging hardware manufacturers of an old computer, the Apple ///. 1-31 is Apple Computer. Very few third parties made hardware so it's very likely I will not encounter another range. Nevertheless I think I will put you suggestion to practice so to better understand it. At least now that the anxiety of getting it done at all is finished!

Comment: Cool! As a hint, when you find yourself writing the same code over and over, where just a few things change (e.g. `if 1 <= mfg <= 31: ... if 39 <= mfg <= 55: ...`) then consider putting the things that change (the start & end values in this case) into a data structure (like a list or a dict), and looping through it.